Prevent CompatTelRunner.exe and TiWorker.exe from running wild on processor, memory and disk
Not sure what Windows Update is actually doing, if it was recompiling the OS and all drivers with system specific PGO-telemetry info I would be more tolerant. However it is not PerfWatson2.exe. One thing is sure they periodically keep draining lots of resources. Especially CompatTelRunner.exe can be using 25% CPU on all 4 cores for hours.
It is possible to tweak how often and when it is triggered (Task Scheduler Library -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Application experience -> Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser). This does help a little so I can schedule it to less demanding hours, but it feels like a workaround and not a solution.
Off course I could switch it off altogether but I do not want to stop updating Windows (though there seems to be another scheduler for WindowsUpdate called Refresh Group Policy Cache and RUXIM\PLUGScheduler), is there any safe way to opt out of whatever these processes are doing without stopping updates?
Are there any alternative ways to keep Windows up to date? For example via an alternative (but trustworthy) package manager (even 3rd party if necessary)?
